# Unable to resolve class - gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, jenkins-groovy

I have directory structure as below:

```
src
   --foo
        --A.groovy
   --test
         --groovy
                 buildTest.groovy
```

This is the A.groovy class :

```
package foo

class A {
   void execute() {
       println "Inside A"
   }
}
```

This my buildTest.groovy

```
class buildTest {
     @Test
     void should_execute(){
        A a = new A()
        def result = a.execute()
     }
}
```

When I run ./gradlew test, it throws error :

```
Unable to resolve class A 
A a = new A()
  ^
```

This is my build.gradle :

```
plugins {
    id "groovy"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/' }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.eclipse.hudson:hudson-core:3.2.1'
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.7'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation "com.lesfurets:jenkins-pipeline-unit:1.3"
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['src/foo']
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone help me in resolving this error.

Comment: why not stick with default `src/main/*` and not bravely fight the windmills of problems?

Comment: You've also stuck A in a folder foo, said it's in the package foo, and then set the srcDirs to include foo, so it will effectively be top-level..  Use `src/main/groovy/foo/A.groovy` and `src/test/groovy/foo/ATest.groovy` as injecteer says, and you can get rid of the `sourceSets` bit where you are fighting to get your non-standard layout to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared a class `A` in package `foo`. (Note that the layout doesn't reflect this as the file should be in `src/foo/foo/A.groovy`, although Groovy doesn't really care).

However, the test class is not in a package and therefore can't see `foo.A`. Either import it or move the test class to package `foo` as well. Alternatively, remove the package declaration from class `A`, though I don't think that is good practice.

I also agree with the comment about not changing the layout unless you have a very good reason for it (e.g. you are working on a legacy project). This is probably what has caused confusion about what package the class is actually in.

Comment: importing the package somehow did not help. But I added the test class also to the package and it worked.